# Python 3: Open file in read mode without raising an exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I am trying to write a block of code which opens a new file every time a Python3 script is run.

I am constructing the filename using an incrementing number.

For example, the following are some examples of valid filenames which should be produced:

```
output_0.csv
output_1.csv
output_2.csv
output_3.csv
```

On the next run of the script, the next filename to be used should be `output_4.csv`.

In C/C++ I would do this in the following way:

- Enter an infinite loop
- Try to open the first filename, in "read" mode
- If the file is open, increment the filename number and repeat
- If the file is not open, break out of the loop and re-open the file in "write" mode

This doesn't seem to work in Python 3, as opening a non-existing file in read mode causes an exception to be raised.

One possible solution might be to move the open file code block inside a try-catch block. But this doesn't seem like a particularly elegant solution.

Here is what I tried so far in code

```
# open a file to store output data
filename_base = "output"
filename_ext = "csv"
filename_number = 0

while True:
    filename_full = f"{filename_base}_{filename_number}.{filename_ext}"
    with open(filename_full, "r") as f:
        if f.closed:
            print(f"Writing data to {filename_full}")
            break
        else:
            print(f"File {filename_full} exists")
            filename_number += 1

with open(filename_full, "w") as f:
    pass
```

As explained above this code crashes when trying to open a file which does not exist in "read" mode.

Comment: The exception is there to inform you "If the file is not open". Catching the exception is how you check it. There is nothing inelegant about this.

Comment: This article may help you, https://dev.to/zhiyueyi/how-to-open-a-file-in-python-like-a-pro-3oe0

Answer (score 5):

Using pathlib you can check with [`Path.is_file()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_file) which returns `True` when it encounters a file or a symbolic link to a file.

```py
from pathlib import Path

filename_base = "output"
filename_ext = "csv"
filename_number = 0

filename_full = f"{filename_base}_{filename_number}.{filename_ext}"
p = Path(filename_full)

while p.is_file() or p.is_dir():
    filename_number += 1
    p = Path(f"{filename_base}_{filename_number}.{filename_ext}")
```

This loop should exit when the file isn’t there so you can open it for writing.

Comment: A nice solution. I see only one potential issue, which is where something, like a directory, exists, and is not a file. Is there a version of this which uses something in place of `is_file()` to detect the presence of any path, rather than just files. (Simlinks, dirs, etc)

Comment: `is_file()` will return True for symbolic links, I've updated the answer a little to account for directories

Answer (score 2):

you can check if a file exists prior using

```
os.path.exists(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the OS module to check if the file path is a file, and then open it:

```
import os

file_path = './file.csv'

if(os.path.isfile(file_path)):
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
filename_base = "output"
filename_ext = "csv"
filename_number = 0

while True:
    filename_full = f"{filename_base}_{filename_number}.{filename_ext}"
    try:
      with open(filename_full, "r") as f:
          print(f"File {filename_full} exists")
          filename_number += 1
    except FileNotFoundError:
      print("Creating new file")
      open(filename_full, 'w');
      break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might `os.path.exists` to check if file already exists for example

```
import os
print(os.path.exists("output_0.csv"))
```

or harness fact that your names

```
output_0.csv
output_1.csv
output_2.csv
output_3.csv
```

are so regular, exploit `glob.glob` like so

```
import glob
existing = glob.glob("output_*.csv")
print(existing)  # list of existing files
```